# PayPal 即時支払い通知(IPN)警告メールが届いたらどう対応しますか

Tags: paypal

PayPalから下記メールが届きましたが、これはどういう意味ですか、どう対応するのでしょうか

### 日本語版：

**** 様

PayPal即時支払い通知(IPN)を処理しているサーバーをご確認ください。以下のURL宛てのIPNが正常に実行されていません。

https://www.xxx.com/xxx

このURLにお心当たりのない場合は、ご契約のサービスプロバイダがお客さまを代行してIPNを使用している可能性があります。サービスプロバイダに連絡して上記の情報を伝えてください。問題が続く場合は、お客さまのアカウントのIPNが無効になる場合があります。

迅速なご対応ありがとうございます。

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

PayPal

パスワードは厳重に管理してください

パスワードは、PayPal従業員を含め、誰にも教えないでください。また、不正なウェブサイトに誤ってアクセスすることのないように、アカウントにログインするたびに新しくウェブブラウザ (Internet Explorer や Firefox 等) を開いて、PayPalの URL を入力するようにしてください。

本メールの送信アドレスは送信専用となっておりますので、このメールへの返信によるご質問、お問い合わせにはお答えしかねます。ご質問・お問い合わせがございましたら、PayPalのホームページの"[ヘルプ]" リンクよりお願いいたします。

Copyright © 2010-2016 PayPal. All rights reserved. PayPal Pte. Ltdはシンガポール法人です。PayPal Pte. Ltdは、資金移動業の役務提供を行う資金移動業者として日本国金融庁に登録されています。関東財務局長第00026号

### 英語版：

Subject: PayPal Instant Payment Notification Warning
Dear ******,

Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN). Instant Payment Notifications sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

URL******

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account.

Thank you for your prompt attention to this issue.

Yours sincerely,
PayPal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

このメールが届いている原因は、一般的にPayPalからIPNメッセージをお客様のサーバーに送信することが一定の期間内に失敗し続けたら、PayPalがお客様のところに送信いたします。
これは支払いが正常に完了していなかったとの意味ではありません。
IPNという機能は、取引が完了した後、PayPalからマーチャントのサイトに取引の詳細を通知する機能です。

通常はマーチャントのサイトでIPN受信プログラムを用意し、IPNメッセージを解析して、サイト上の注文管理システムの情報や注文ステータスを更新します。
IPNの受信機能が異常になると、御社のサイトの注文ステータスなどが更新されなくなると思います。

具体的な異常原因についてはPayPalのアカウントで即時支払通知履歴で確認する必要があります。
即時支払履歴はwww.paypal.comでログインしてから、下記URLにアクセスして、
https://www.paypal.com/jp/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-ipns-history&nav=0%2e2%2e5
即時支払通知履歴画面で日付範囲または取引IDを指定して検索したら、送付したIPNが表示されます。
その中にステータスが失敗のIPNがあるはずです、失敗のIPNのメッセージIDをクリックすると、IPN送信詳細は表示されます。

IPN詳細画面に「HTTP 応答コード」という項目があります、成功のIPNに対して、このコードは200となっており、失敗のIPNに対しては200以外のコードになります。
このコードはPayPalサーバーからIPNをマーチャントのIPN受信URLに送信する際、マーチャントのサーバーからのHTTPレスポンスです。
HTTP 200はOKという意味で、サーバー側がIPN受信成功を意味しています、200以外のコードは何らかの原因でサーバー側がエラーになり、IPN受信失敗を意味しています。
PayPal側が200以外のレスポンスを受け取ったら、IPN受信失敗と見なし、マーチャントにIPN警告メールを送付します。
HTTP 応答コードについて下記URLを参考してください。
https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B9%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89

ですので、この異常の解決はPayPal側ではなく、マーチャントのサーバー側になります。
マーチャント側でこのレスポンスコードを見て、なぜサーバー側のIPN受信URLが受信失敗したかを調査する必要があります。
もしサードパーティーのショッピングカートシステムを利用している場合は、ショッピングカートのほうに問い合わせてください。

もしマーチャントサイトのオーダー関連ステータス更新処理などがこのIPN機能に依存しない場合は、IPN機能を無効にしてください。
無効した後、このメールは届かなくなります。

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask